# TFS Migration to new server with new Name

Tags: tfs, database-migration

I am moving my current On-premise  TFS 2018.2 & SQL 2016 to TFS 2018.3 on a new Local server with SQL server 2016 .

Both will be on the same domain with different name .

What should be the correct procedure?

**Option 1**

1. Restore DB on new SQL instance - Different name (Using SQL restore)
2. Rename DB [Rename Computer with SQL Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/rename-a-computer-that-hosts-a-stand-alone-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)
3. Install New TFS 2018.3 and connect to New SQL Instance

**Option 2**

1. Install TFS 2018.3
2. Restore DB from old Server [(Using TFS restore)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the easiest is to install a new instance of TFS on your new SQL instance.

Then [detach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/manage-team-project-collections#detach-or-delete-a-project-collection) the collection from the source TFS instance, backup up the collection's db, restore it to the new SQL environment and then attach it in the new TFS instance.

Comment: This is ok - but the new Instance has a new name

Comment: the new name does not matter from a TFS point of view if you go the detach - attach route.

Comment: Detach a DB and attach to another SQL instance ?

Comment: In this instance attach and detach is relating to the TFS operations. The SQL would be backup and restore. Yes you can backup and restore to "any" SQL instance and then attach it to TFS.